# optimize_for_inference library in Tensorflow is no longer working

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, object-detection

I have a frozen trained model for object detection that has already been tested on videos. I wanna optimize the model using the `optimize_for_inference` library using this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib


input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.Open("frozen_inference_graph.pb", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)

output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
        input_graph_def,
        ['input'],  ## input
        ['y_'], ## output
        tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

f = tf.gfile.FastGFile("./inference_graph/optimized_inference_graph.pb", "wb")
f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

I tested the generated `optimized_inference_graph.pb` but it issued this error during testing:

> DecodeError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5     with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
>         6         serialized_graph = fid.read()
>   ----> 7         od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
>         8         tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
>         9
>
> DecodeError: Error parsing message

Is this library no longer available? Is it replaced by `transform
_graph`?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to ```od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)``` ?